# unable to install npm bcrypt on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sails.js, bcrypt

I am trying to install bcrypt to use it with sails js and passport on an ubuntu system but unable to install it. On running he command to install bcrypt following log is generated on the terminal:

```
    manav@tantraadmin:~$ npm install bcrypt
            \
            > bcrypt@0.8.0 install /home/manav/node_modules/bcrypt
            > node-gyp rebuild

            make: Entering directory `/home/manav/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
              CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
            make: g++: Command not found
            make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 127
            make: Leaving directory `/home/manav/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
            gyp ERR! build error 
            gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
            gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/manav/.nvm/v0.10.31/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
            gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
            gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
            gyp ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
            gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/manav/.nvm/v0.10.31/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
            gyp ERR! cwd /home/manav/node_modules/bcrypt
            gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.31
            gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
            gyp ERR! not ok 
            npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
            npm ERR! Exit status 1
            npm ERR! 
            npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.0 install script.
            npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
            npm ERR! not with npm itself.
            npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
            npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
            npm ERR! You can get their info via:
            npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
            npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

            npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
            npm ERR! command "/home/manav/.nvm/v0.10.31/bin/node" "/home/manav/.nvm/v0.10.31/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
            npm ERR! cwd /home/manav
            npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
            npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
            npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
            npm ERR! 
            npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
            npm ERR!     /home/manav/npm-debug.log
            npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you simply miss compiler g++ (sudo apt-get install g++)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to `sudo apt-get install build-essential python2.7` to install a compiler and other tools because `bcrypt` is an addon that needs to be compiled.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was having a heck of a time trying to install node-bcrypt with node v4.1.1, and this is what finally got it working for me.

Comment: Just `sudo apt install build-essential` is enough for me on Ubuntu 16.04 to get bcrypt installation working.

Answer (score 1):

**ERROR!!!!**

```
  > bcrypt@0.8.7 install /var/www/YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR/node_modules/bcrypt
  > node-gyp rebuild

  make: Entering directory '/var/www/pedestrian/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
    SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
    COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
  make: Leaving directory '/var/www/YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
```

**You can use both commands for fixing bcrypt addon issue:**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python2.7
```

OR

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

After I installed ubuntu 17.10 I had very similar errors with `node-gyp`. What worked for me was installing the node-gyp module `apt-get install node-gyp`

Answer (score 0):

With a similar issue on Ubuntu, what worked for me was installing `bcryptjs` instead of `bcrypt`. Try it out